# How deep should I encase electrical wire in concrete slab

Tags: electrical, slab

I need to run electrical in concrete slab indoors, I am planning to use 1/2 flexible PVC conduit. It is a residential slab indoors.

How deep should I bury it?
Is there any code station the depth?

Comment: If this is a suspended (overhead) slab, don't do it without consulting a structural engineer. If it is a slab on grade, place the pipe at the mid-height. I suggest maintaining a minimum of 2.5" clear cover, top, and bottom. You need to ensure and prevent the pipe from damage during concreting.

Comment: It is slab on grade. So you are saying 2,5 above the conduit? But if the slab is 6" and the conduit is 1/2 then I basically will take out half the depth.

Comment: An NEC rule relating to AFCIs says that 2" *of cover* under concrete is as good as metal conduit for fire prevention. For instance if the conduit run from service panel to first receptacle is buried in 2" of concrete, the AFCI can be at the first receptacle instead of the breaker.

Comment: Correct, 6" was my intention. You shall have wire mesh or rebar reinforcement near the top with a minimum of 2" clear cover, then tie the pipe beneath the reinforcing steel. Do not allow the worker to stand directly on the reinforcing nor the pipe, use wood board strips throughout the placement.

Comment: Are you talking about LFNC liquid tight flexible non metallic conduit? If rated for direct burial it can be below the slab or in the slab. When you say bury it can be at ground level and poured over (make sure not to step on it it can collapse).
Smurf tube or ENT can not be used in this case. If I wanted it in the concrete I would put it below 2’ because single plate walls when set with 3-1/2” anchors may penetrate it if shallower.

Comment: Yes I am thinking liquidtite conduit

Comment: If the pipe is actually run through concrete, rigid PVC withstands abuse during concrete install while still being cheap and extremely easy to run, and if you use rebar on blocks rather than just mesh, you can securely tie the pipe to it and carefully walk on it during concrete pour.  Core line or "smurf tube" is viable as well and even easier to install, but requires more monitoring as it can be crushed, shattered (when cold) or punctured by a reckless pour.  One other note, Any time you're running a pipe that would be hard to run again in the future, consider upgrading it or running a spare.

Comment: With plastic conduit types, it may be necessary to transition to metal conduit before exiting the concrete.  Any time you bury or embed a pipe in a high rework area like a backyard, take measurements and pictures that can be used to accurately locate it in the future and one day you or a future homeowner may save a lot of money.